# Convert commas to dots in txt with python that also contains scientific number formatting

Tags: python, text

I have a text file ( huge ) with all numbers separated with a combination of spaces and tabs between them and with comma for decimal and after decimal separation, while the first column is scientific formatted and the next ones are numbers but with commas. I just put the first row here  as numbers :

> 0,0000000E00     -2,7599284          -1,3676726          -1,7231264          -1,0558825          -1,8871096          -3,0763804          -3,2206187          -3,2308111          -2,3147060          -3,9572818          -4,0232415          -4,2180738

the file is so huge that a notepad++ can't process it to convert the "," to "."

So what I do is :

```
with open(file) as fp:
    line = fp.readline()
    cnt = 1
    while line:
        digits=re.findall(r'([\d.:]+)', line)
        s=line
        s = s.replace('.','').replace(',','.')
        number = float(s)
        cnt += 1
```

I tried even to use digits, but that causes to divide the first column in two numbers :

[image: output-digits]

and eventually the error I get when using .replace command. what I would have prefered was to convert the commas to dots regardless of disturbing formats like scientific. I appreciate your help

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: ' 00000000E00
>   \t-29513521      \t-17002219      \t-22375536      \t-14994097
>   \t-24163610      \t-34076621      \t-31233623      \t-32341597
>   \t-24724552      \t-42434935      \t-43454237      \t-44885144
>   \n'

I also put ***how the input looks like*** in txt ***and how I need it in output*** ( in csv format )

input seems like this :

**first line :**

between 1st and 2nd column : 3 spaces + 1 Tab

between rest of columns : 6 spaces + 1 Tab

**second line and on :**

between 1st and 2nd column : 2 spaces + 1 Tab

between rest of columns : 6 spaces + 1 Tab

this is a screen shot of the ***txt input file*** :
***Attention :*** there is one space in the beginning of each line

[image: input-txt]

and what I want as ***output is csv file*** with separated columns with " ; "

[image]

Comment: Would there be a problem with just reading the entire file into a string in Python, and then doing a global replacement of `,` to `.` ?

Comment: if that works, yes, it will read all the numbers in string anyway right ? shall you please kindly write the code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try reading the entire file into a Python string, and then doing a global replacement of comma to dot:

```
data = ""
with open('nums.csv', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read().replace(',', '.').replace(' ', ';')

with open("nums_out.csv", "w") as out_file:
    out_file.write(data)
```

For a possibly more robust solution, should there exist the possibility that two columns could be separated by *multiple* whitespace characters, use `re.sub`:

```
data = ""
with open('nums.csv', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read().replace(',', '.')
    data = re.sub(r'(?<=\n|^)[^\S\r\n]+', '', data)
    data = re.sub('(?<=\S)[^\S\r\n]+', ';', data)
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! how can I impose tab separated ( ;) lines in csv while writing 
 with open(filename+'.csv', "w") as out_file: ?

Comment: Hi Fabio, just chain another call to `replace()`, and replace space with semicolon.

Comment: one problem with the new solution : the .replace(' ', ';') creates many empty columns

Comment: That's not a problem if there are missing data.  But in case you have multiple whitespace characters, then check my updated answer.

Comment: Yes Exactly ! some have 2 spaces , some 4 spaces, and there is even Tab !!

Comment: There is still problem >> All of the data were written in one line, I mean the order of the input data was lost

Comment: Updated, sorry about that, I can't test this locally for a few reasons.

Comment: dear @Tim It works now !! Amazing !! just one empty column is left on the left end. how to drop it right befor writing ?

Comment: I mean, the lines now start with a " ; " since there was one space at the beginning of each line

Comment: just a curiosity, is it possible to write the data to xlsx instead of csv ?

Comment: You would need a Python Excel library to do that; Excel files are binary, not plain text.

Comment: well since I read from Text, can I use xlswrite using the same variable "data" we created ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Can we select certain commas only from the CSV, meaning the first and the last comma to be replaced, instead of all commas with another special character. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you're working with tabular data in python, you'll want to use the pandas package. It's a large package, so if this is a one-off, the overhead of installing it might not be worth it.

Pandas has a [read_csv function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) that deals with this easily, and the result can be exported to csv:

```
import pandas as pd
dataframe = pd.read_csv("input.txt", sep="\s+", decimal=",")
dataframe.to_csv("output.csv", sep=";", header=False, index=False)
```

Note: if your original file has no header, also pass `header=None` to the `read_csv` function.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're converting the entire string to a float, which python won't recognize. It will recognize the floats and even the scientific notation when you try to cast them separately.

What you could do is [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) the line using `str.split()`. Without arguments, the split function will split on any whitespace character including `'\t'`. You can then convert each to a float and rebuild the string.

```
with open(file) as fp:
    line = fp.readline()
    cnt = 1
    while line:
        digits=re.findall(r'([\d.:]+)', line)
        s=line
        s = s.replace('.','').replace(',','.')

        # Split the string into a list of strings
        s_list = s.split()

        # Convert each string to a float
        for i, num in enumerate(s_list):
            s_list[i] = float(num)

        # Rebuild the string for further use
        s = " \t".join(s_list)
        cnt += 1
```